# Can someone come up with a kivy python code where we define keys and values

Tags: python, terminal, kivy, kivymd, correctness

If we give any key as the input we should get the corresponding values as the output and if we give any one element from a list as input, we should get the corresponding key as the output.Please ignore `enter code here` in the middle

Following is keys and their values

"RCB" : ["Virat", "Abd", "Maxwell","Chahal"],
"CSK": ["Dhoni", "Raina", "Jadeja", "Faf"],
"KKR": ["Morgan", "Russell", "Karthik", "Na`enter code here`ine"],
"PBKS" : ["Rahul", "Mayank", "Shami", "Gayle"]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
dict = {
    "RCB" : ["Virat", "Abd", "Maxwell","Chahal"], 
    "CSK": ["Dhoni", "Raina", "Jadeja", "Faf"],
    "KKR": ["Morgan", "Russell", "Karthik", "Naenter code hereine"],
    "PBKS" : ["Rahul", "Mayank", "Shami", "Gayle"]
}

def getOutput(dict, value):
    try:
        output = dict[value]
        return output
    except KeyError:
        for key in dict:
            if value in dict[key]:
                output = key
                return output
    return None

print(getOutput(dict, "RCB")) 
#["Virat", "Abd", "Maxwell","Chahal"]
print(getOutput(dict, "Raina"))
#"CSK"
```

Comment: It should take input from the user...like for Eg: If he gives 'PBKS' as the input then he should get "Rahul", "Mayank", "Shami", "Gayle" as the output and the vice versa of it, for Eg: if he gives 'Gayle' as the input he should get 'PBKS' as the output. I executed the above code, it gave me : Virat", "Abd", "Maxwell","Chahal" and CSK as the output

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it exactly what you wanted?